# How change in potential energy corresponds to change in enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, enthalpy, reaction-coordinate

So while reading about activation energy , I came across this graph :

[image]

Here, change in potential energy of reactant and product is depicted as ${ΔH}$, but at constant pressure and temperature , shouldn't that be ${ΔU}$. Because change in thermal energy is zero, So change in potential energy should be ${ΔU}$.

According to me, that gap in the graph should be equal to ${Q}$ + ${W}$ not just ${Q}$ (${=ΔH}$).

This snap from 'Wiley's Solomons, Fryhle & Snyder Organic Chemistry' also conveys that change in potential energy is ${ΔH}$ .

[image]

Comment: Why do you say change in thermal energy is 0 ? At constant p and T, heat going in / out = $\Delta H$

Comment: Constant T doesn't mean no heat flow. Thus, e.g., if a reaction evolves thermal energy, the thermal energy flows out of the system to maintain constant T.

Comment: I never said heat flow is zero . Thermal energy is proportional to Temperature , So as ΔT=0 wouldn't the change in thermal energy be zero. I think it this way as ΔU = Δ(Thermal energy) + ΔPE . (U meaning Internal Energy)

Comment: According to me, that gap in the graph should be equal to Q + W not just Q (=ΔH).

Comment: Does U depend on just T and P, or do you think that it might also depend on chemical composition?

Comment: @ChetMiller I think U contains both thermal (Kinetic) energy and potential energy of the molecules , and thermal energy is dependent on the temperature (maybe also on pressure for real gases ) while potential energy is dependent on the the chemical composition ,So that way I guess it should be dependent both on temperature and chemical composition.

Comment: Right, so the products have different U than the reactants, even at the same temperature.

Comment: Yes , no problem with that

Comment: @ChetMiller But it doesn't answers my query.

Comment: Can anybody please help me out ? If question isn't clear to you please let me know !

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are confused about. So: (1) You are correct that U contains both thermal  E (TE) (thermal energy = kinetic energy) and potential E (PE). (2) You are incorrect in saying that $\Delta T = 0$ means same TE. The products and reactants will (with rare exceptions) have diff. heat capacities, and thus contain different amounts of TE at the same T. (3)You are right to be confused by the graph. Its vertical axis is mislabeled.   Neither $\Delta H$ nor $\Delta U$ equal the change in PE, even at const. T (see #2).

Comment: (4) Is the graph from a published work or some other publicly-available source (e.g., the internet)?  If so, you need to give proper attribution (even if the graph is wrong), and indicate the source.   (5)  See my answer here, which directly addresses your question:   https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77414/is-enthalpy-the-same-thing-as-potential-energy/121235#121235

Comment: @theorist I got what you are saying , the diagram is originally from here https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introductory_Chemistry_(CK-12)/18%3A_Kinetics/18.04%3A_Potential_Energy_Diagrams but I found similar graph and statements in other books also.

Comment: On Wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy , in a diagram the difference between the energy of product and reaction is labeled as ΔH , but it isn't clear that Energy labeled on Y-axis is which energy (Potential , Total , gibbs free ..) ?